# Set colors in asp.net pie chart by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have an a chart control which measures customer satisfaction.

The possible values are Happy, Neutral and Sad. (e.g. a possible set of values might be: Happy (23), Neutral (12), Sad (19) )

I want Happy to always be Green, Neutral to always be Orange and Sad to always be Red (e.g. like a RAG status)

I set the colors thus:

> fbChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
>              fbChart.PaletteCustomColors = new Color[] { Color.Green, Color.Orange, Color.Red };

This works fine if all three possible options have values, but if there is only one or two with values the colors screws up. (e.g. If I have Happy (12) and Sad (9) but no Neutral, the colors come out as Green for Happy and Orange for Sad.)

Is there a way I can tie down the colors to the name (e.g Happy / Neutral / Sad)?

EDIT:

The data is loaded into the chart from a datatable:

```
    var fb = from f in db.tl_feedbacks
             where f.timestamp >= new DateTime(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 0, 0, 0) &&                f.timestamp <= new DateTime(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 23, 59, 59)  
               group f by f.tl_feedback_score.score into grp
               select new
               {
                     Score = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(grp.Key),  
                     Count = grp.Select(x => x.tl_feedback_score.score).Count()  
               };  
              fbChart.Series["Feedback"].XValueMember = "Score";  
              fbChart.Series["Feedback"].YValueMembers = "Count";

              fbChart.DataSource = fb;
              fbChart.DataBind();
```

Comment: how did you bind your data to the charts ....through datatable ?

Comment: @errorstacks - yes, see above for code (added it as an edit)

Comment: if that code is not working then pls let me know....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you are binding data to the charts using datatable and you are using asp.net chart controls......

I am hoping that this solution will helps you

```
foreach (Series charts in fbchart.Series)
{
    foreach (DataPoint point in charts.Points)
    {
       switch (point.AxisLabel)
        {
           case "Neutral": point.Color = Color.Red; break;
           case "Happy": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
           case "Sad": point.Color = Color.Orange; break;
         }
         point.Label = string.Format("{0:0} - {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel);

    }
 }
```

and the example image(chart) for the above code is like this...Below[image: dividing areas with membership types using pie chart controls]